# Change List Value Everytime User Cliked The Button (Python-Flask)

Tags: python, list, flask, button

I'm new on learning Python and Flask.
So, in route.py I have a list that defines below:

```
symptoms = [0 for i in range (27)]
```

And then I want to change the list value every time I click the button, when user klik "yes", it changes the list in [index] element as 1. And when user click "no" it changes the list in [index] element as 0. Here is my html:

```
<div name="index_ke" value="0" class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-2">

            <input type="submit" name='cek_diagnose' value='0' class="u-border-2 u-border-black u-btn u-button-style u-hover-black u-none u-text-black u-text-hover-white u-btn-1">NO</input>
            <input type="submit" name='cek_diagnose' value='1' class="u-border-2 u-border-black u-btn u-button-style u-hover-black u-none u-text-black u-text-hover-white u-btn-2">YES</input>
```

So I have 27 div's that contain theese 2 button with all have same name that carried value 0 and 1. Then here's my route.py:

```
symptoms = [0 for i in range (27)]
@app.route('/tests', methods = ['POST'])
def tests():
    return render_template('index.html', scroll='tests')
def change_list():
    if request.method == 'POST':
      index = int(request.form.get("index_ke"))
      symptoms[index] = int(request.form.get("cek_diagnose"))
```

From the variable index, I want to save the div's name "index_ke" with value from 0 until 26 to know the index, and I want change the value of symptoms in element[index] by the value that carried by the button. Is it correct or there is another way? Please give me some suggestion about it and how I can check my list value? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are making 27 buttons , jinja2 for loop or just using html.

Comment: just using HTML, manually

Comment: I have 27 divs, every div have 2 buttons

Comment: ok so what you want is that when user click on a button then a value should be send which should contain index and the value 1 or 0 (on and off), are you using form tag or ajax/fetch api something like to send data.

Comment: yes exactly! I'm using form tag in html with method post. the action =/tests

Comment: I answered the question, if you want any other way to do this, then you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in many ways. I will use ajax and jquery(javascript).
Inlcude jquery in html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js" ></script>
```

html

```
{% for i in range(27) %}
<button type="button" id="0" value="{{loop.index}}" class="my_btn_class u-border-2 u-border-black u-btn u-button-style u-hover-black u-none u-text-black u-text-hover-white u-btn-1">off</button>
<button type="button" id="1" value="{{loop.index}}" class="my_btn_class u-border-2 u-border-black u-btn u-button-style u-hover-black u-none u-text-black u-text-hover-white u-btn-1">on</button>
{% endfor %}
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".my_btn_class").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: `${window.location.pathname}`,
        data: {
            index : this.value, // index is key in request.post.get("index")
            cek_diagnose : this.id // same as above request.post.get("cek_diagnose") 
        },
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        },
    });
})
})
```

python

```
index = int(request.form.get("index"))
symptoms[index] = int(request.form.get("cek_diagnose"))
```

What you return it will be logged in browser console.